# Functional that leads to hollow

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

Consider a field $\phi(x,y)$ in the 2D plane. The minimum of the following Functional leads to formation of a 2D disk in which $\phi(x,y)=1$ deep inside the disk and $\phi(x,y)=0$ outside the disk.The boundary of the disk has a thickness so that $\phi$ continuously gors from 1 to 0.
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{\operatorname{d\!}}
F=\int \Dm x \Dm y \big(\phi^2(1-\phi)^2 + K (\nabla \phi)^2 \big)
$$
with $K>0$ and a constraint on $\phi$ as following: $\int \phi dx dy =c$ where $c>>1$.

Is it possible to add a term to the above functional so that the minimum of $F$ becomes a disk with a hollow circle at the centre? I thought about considering a term which favours negative curvature like $-\nabla^2 \phi$, but since this term can be written as a divergence, its integral is zero and would not change the $F$.

I would appreciate it if some one could clarify if this question has a solution or not.

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to proceed at this point, I was just inferring from the context of Cahn-Hilliard (which is what your functional is, just with the usual attractor of $-1$ moved to $0$).

Comment: What class of functions are you taking the minimum? Are they functions defined on the disk only?

Comment: \phi is defined everywhere. Minimising F (introduced above) gives zero outside the disk and 1 inside the disk. @ArcticChar

Comment: But your $\phi$ is not really differentiable right? It's not even weakly differentiable.

Comment: It is differentiable, why not? @ArcticChar

Comment: It's not continuous right?

Comment: It is continuous in the sense that the boundary of the disk has a thickness and does not go from 1 to 0 suddenly. @ArcticChar

Comment: I have modified the question @ArcticChar

Comment: Can you explain the constraints of the minimization? Clearly $\phi \equiv 0$ is better than your proposed "droplet" solution.

Comment: The constraint on $\phi$ is $\int \phi dx dy =c$ where $c>1$. @Ian

Comment: But your proposed solution looks to have $\int \phi $ roughly $\pi$, which might not be $c$.

Comment: Anyway, it is not clear how the unit disc comes into play.

Comment: $\int \phi $ is not equal to $\pi$ as it also depends on the radius of the disk. @ArcticChar

Comment: Is an explicitly spatially dependent term acceptable, like $\phi^2/r$ or something?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the space is homogeneous so the disk could be anywhere.  @Ian

Comment: @Ian do you know how to do this with a spatially dependent term?